# JS file is loaded in HTML (generated via Markdown) but not executing

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

The HTML file is generated using Markdown.
I have included a JavaScript file in HTML. It is visible that it is loaded in the browser (tried on Mozilla firefox).

See the proof below.
[image]

I tested if JS is enabled or not from https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-javascript-enabled

[image]

But somehow, it is not being executed.

Below is my generated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-16"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
<meta name="generator" content="Bootply-JBake-Custom"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16"/>

<title>Title</title>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/asciidoctor.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/prettify.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="prettyPrint()">
    <div id="wrap">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="/index.html" class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                          <li><a href="/projects/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/categories.html">Categories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header" id="banner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Projects</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <!-- This script is loading but not executing -->
         <script type="text /javascript" src="projects.js"></script>
<p>Here is the list of projects</p>

    </div>
        </div>
        <div id="push"></div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

projects.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("ready")
alert("hi");
});

console.log("loaded")
```

Comment: Uhm... I just noticed this is just your debug view, try setting the scripts `type` attribute without the space.

Comment: tried : <script type="text/javascript" src="projects.js"/>
not helping :(

Comment: `script` tags can not be self closing

Comment: The previous comment said not to provide body.. :(

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="projects.js"></script>
worked.
Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, but not using a body does not imply having it self closing.

Comment: Is the script actually found ? What does dev tools show for the request to the script, all pathes you define are absolute with the only exception beeing the scripts path.

Comment: yes, it worked. spacing was the issue.

Comment: @LJᛃ Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Well this question will be closed as a typo question anyway ;)

Comment: I guess this should be a common problem when the HTML is generated through MarkDown converter. So It might be helpful.

Comment: Well, you never mentioned that it was generated using markdown, not in your title, not in your question nor as a tag...

Comment: @LJᛃ added the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<script type="text /javascript" src="projects.js"></script>`

Remove the space in `type="text /javascript` with the result:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="projects.js"></script>`

This should allow the browser to parse the HTML correctly and load the script.

EDIT: Or remove the `type` attribute from the `<script>` tag entirely, as suggested by the comment below.

Comment: You can just remove the `type` entirely.  If it is not specified, then the browser treats it as javascript.  This has been browser's behavior for a long time and was codified in specification in HTML5