# Markdown4j adding space if Script is included in markdown

Tags: html, markdown, markdown4j

I have a markdown file which includes a script e.g.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="projects.js"></script>
```

After conversion the output is like

```
<script type="text /javascript" src="projects.js"></script>
```

Notice the extra space after **text** and before **/javascript**.
This stops the execution of javascript (PS [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701690/js-file-is-loaded-but-not-executing)

I am using markdown4j for this.
How to fix the issue?  ( I know the workaround of not specifying **type**) but I want to fix the issue itself.

Comment: I would say this is a bug in the Markdown parser you are using as it [works fine](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%3Cscript+type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22+src%3D%22projects.js%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E) in most implementations.I would suggest reporting the bug to the developers of the implementation you are using.

Comment: @Waylan Thanks. Can you post that as an answer, so that I can accept it?